# Azure Table Storage return 404 resource not found called by API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-account

I want to query table storage in Azure. Im using url like:

```
https://SA-name.table.core.windows.net/table-name()
```

and i get a response:

```
ResourceNotFound The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:id Time:2022-03-18T07:25:18.4393071Z
```

My question is, how to set `Table storage` in `Storage account` to public access?

Answer (score 0):

The error maybe  because, while creating the Azure table, the Access level is private by default and not allowing to access the resources.

But
please [**Note:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#:%7E:text=Every%20request%20made%20against%20a%20storage%20service%20must%20be%20authorized%2C%20unless%20the%20request%20is%20for%20a%20blob%20or%20container%20resource%20that%20has%20been%20made%20available%20for%20public%20or%20signed%20access) that **Only  Azure blobs or blob containers can be given unauthenticated public access.**

> Every request made against a storage service must be authorized,
> unless the request is for a blob or container resource that has been
> made available for public or signed access. Azure Storage supports
> optional anonymous public read access for *containers and blobs*. By
> default, anonymous access to your data is never permitted.

You need to provide request with Authorization header as explained here:[authorize-with-shared-key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#table-service-shared-key-authorization)

Or use a shared access signature, as described here:[storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

The access policy portion of the URI indicates the period of time over which the shared access signature is valid and the permissions to be granted to the user. [specifying-the-access-policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#specifying-the-access-policy)